# Do cats sometimes bite a person just for fun?

Tags: cats

My cat often bites me, and it hurts sometimes and does not sometimes.

For me, it seems that he does not intend to attack or threat me, but just to play with me.

Do cats always bite people to really hurt people, or sometimes bite just for fun?

Edit:
My cat is an American short-hair, 12-year-old, male, and weighs about 8kg (17.6 lbs). I cannot describe concretely when he 'bites' me but it happens usually I play with him.

My question was not about my cat only, but about cats in general. But it makes sense that it may be my own cat's unique habit.

Comment: wellcome to pets,can you please add a bit more information about your cat,indoors or outdoors and the age of your cat.some information about when the biting happens like before or after play,before or after eating,is the cat on your lap or on the floor?things like that.

Comment: In my personal experience the small ones do tend to bite (with very little force) which is not associated with attack or threatening you, but I cant associate it with fun either as I dont know whats going on in its head, but a cat did it on my  lateral malleolus bone (while casually rubbing against my leg) which I immediately shook to deter. Maybe its just instinct like kid put almost every toy in their mouth.

Comment: @trondhansen I intended to ask about the entire cats, but your comment makes sense. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, cats "play bite" in general, but most of them stop the behavior when they grow up.

All young mammals I know of play to develop their muscles and motor control and to train hunting or fighting motions. For cats that includes pouncing play mates and grabbing or biting them. It's possible that kittens also play bite humans during play.

Another possibility is that cats gently bite to express their disagreement to being touched in a certain way. My own cat doesn't like to be touched at the belly and immediately bites my hand, but only to pull it away from her belly, not to hurt me. If a cat suddenly starts biting you when you touch it, it may have a painful medical condition like arthritis or a skin infection and you should schedule a checkup with your vet.

Comment: Adding to this answer, cats tend to have a very high level of control over the intensity of their bites. Somewhat gentle bites which do not draw blood are often used as a final warning when you do something they strongly disagree with. If a bite is intended to do real damage, it absolutely will do so and likely require medical attention as well. Side note, one of our cats has no teeth left, and she will actually "bite" instead of swipe with her claws as a warning.

Comment: @bgse did you remove the teeths from your cat?

Comment: @user0193 Yes, they had to be removed since severe gingivitis she had as a complication from FeLV led to bad tooth decay at a young age. Initially we could save the four canines and a couple of teeth in the back, but when those deteriorated as well, the vet advised to remove all remaining teeth in one session as even those that could be kept would not last long and reducing the amount of surgeries was the better choice. Turns out it was the correct choice, she was very happy when she woke up from surgery, so she must have been in a lot more pain already than we or the vet assumed.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that cats use their mouths for a lot of things we would use our hands for, so a grab at a hand may just be a grab, not a bite per se. That can be play, or "Hey, enough petting". I don't know how to describe how to read the cat's intention, but I've found that with most cats, in most situations, I can let the cat go ahead and nip and trust that they'll be as careful as they would be with another cat.

Also, I've known cats which like to mouth their human's fingers when being petted; best guess I've got is that it reminds them of suckling as kittens.

Answer (score 0):

Cats definitely will bite as part of play. Though it really varies between individual cats how much they bite as part of play and how gently (or not) they do it.  Some cats, when they get too bored or have too much excess energy, will try to initiate play with people by pouncing on them and biting as if the person is another cat.

It is generally recommended to discourage your cat from any sort of play wrestling with your hands, because that's a very common way that cat owners end up bitten or scratched. If you sense the cat is getting wound up, or if the cat tries to wrestle with you, get a toy for it to play with instead. Also refrain from any handling that the cat might interpret as play wrestling, such as rough petting.

That said, there is the rare cat that is so gentle with play wrestling that their owners can wrestle with them without getting injured. Most cats, though, aren't that good about it, since it's kind of hard for them to not accidentally scratch a human at all when humans don't have a protective layer of fur like cats do.